# A word for a machine that can generate every possible combination

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, computing

Let's say we have a machine whose sole purpose is to generate every possible combination from sets/columns of values.

Examples:

```
Single column.
Column 1 values: 1, 2, 3  

Generated output: 
1 
2 
3


Double column.
Column 1 values: 1, 2, 3  
Column 2 values: 1, 2, 3

Generated output:  
11 
21 
31
12
22
32
13
23 
33
```

What could we call such a device?

Comment: Brute-forcer? Enumerator? I think a little more context is needed here. Also do note that asking for names for a programming variable is [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Brute-forcer is way too specialised, the machine doesn't care how its output will be used. Enumerator is closer but not quite related to combinations/permutations.

Comment: Once you have perfected your **combinatorial-calculator-inator**, you'll be poised to take over the Tri-State Area!

Comment: I considered **Combinator** but that means something else in the math world [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic), and **Permutator**, but apparently Permutation relates to all possible combinations in a specific order, whereas my machine doesn't care about order.

Comment: I'd call it an **enumerator**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like *permutator* (self-coined in the comments), then go with that. It does have [another meaning in an electrical context](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permutator), but no one will confuse your use of the term with that.

The "order matters" aspect of permutations *is* part of the machine you described. If we're talking about combinations in a rigorous mathematical sense, then your machine should only generate 6 lines of output for 2 columns (instead of 9 lines), since 21 is the same combination as 12; 31 is the same combination as 13; and 32 is the same combination as 23.

Personally, I find there is too much emphasis on single-word solutions. For a machine this specialized, I think two words are warranted. *Permutation enumerator* would be an apt (albeit somewhat prosaic) name for such a machine.

Also, multiple people have suggested *enumerator* in the comments now, and that would be a fine single-word name, since enumeration has the connotation of "listing every possible option". (It was also the first single-word response that popped into my head when I read the question.)

Answer (score 1):

If you think of the items in each column as a set, then you are referring to the [**Cartesian product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

*Example:* Consider the set {1,2} and the set {a,b,c}. The Cartesian product, denoted with the multiplication symbol, as in {1,2}×{a,b,c}, is given by:

{ (1,a), (1,b), (1,c), (2,a), (2,b), (2,c) }

So, what I'm saying is that there is not (as far as I'm aware) one specific word that captures what you're looking for and is also consistent with the relevant mathematical terminology. The suggestion of **permutator** is NOT a good one because "permutation" refers to a *reordering* of the elements of a set, not creating all possible pairs of combinations from two sets. "Taking the Cartesian product" is a valid phrase that embodies exactly what you're doing in your example. If you seek *one word* for this process then you are essentially asking for one to be created just for this purpose.

Comment: That names the result, not the device.

Comment: @MetaEd Okay, but I'm not aware of one word that represents such a device, only "taking the Cartesian product". Should I add this to my answer?